# Hibernate Mapped Composite Key ManyToMany results in ClassCastException

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, hql, classcastexception

I am struggling with a hibernate problem since hours and can not find any help on any website. I've read dozens of tutorials, tried everything but I always end up with a class cast exception or compilation errors.

My schema in this particular part of the database  (mysql innodb) are Plane and Steward. They share a Many2Many relationship.

Using Hibernate Code Generation and Hibernate Tools I generated all POJO classes and the mapping files (including a FlightHasStewardId and FlightHasSteward -> Mapped Composite ID).

I now want to read out all stewards on flight 100!

Notice: Reading other entities works, just M2M reading results in ClassCastEX.

Here my input:

Mapping of FlightHasSteward:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Jan 1, 2014 1:52:14 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.0.0 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="FlightHasSteward" table="Flight_has_Steward" catalog="project3flight">
        <composite-id name="id" class="FlightHasStewardId">
            <key-property name="flightIdflight" type="int">
                <column name="Flight_idflight" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="stewardIdsteward" type="int">
                <column name="Steward_idsteward" />
            </key-property>
        </composite-id>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

FlightHasSteward.java:

```
// default package
// Generated Jan 1, 2014 1:52:14 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.0.0

/**
 * FlightHasSteward generated by hbm2java
 */
public class FlightHasSteward implements java.io.Serializable {

    private FlightHasStewardId id;

    public FlightHasSteward() {
    }

    public FlightHasSteward(FlightHasStewardId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public FlightHasStewardId getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(FlightHasStewardId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

FlightHasStewardId.java:

```
// default package
// Generated Jan 1, 2014 1:52:14 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.0.0

/**
 * FlightHasStewardId generated by hbm2java
 */
public class FlightHasStewardId implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int flightIdflight;
    private int stewardIdsteward;

    public FlightHasStewardId() {
    }

    public FlightHasStewardId(int flightIdflight, int stewardIdsteward) {
        this.flightIdflight = flightIdflight;
        this.stewardIdsteward = stewardIdsteward;
    }

    public int getFlightIdflight() {
        return this.flightIdflight;
    }

    public void setFlightIdflight(int flightIdflight) {
        this.flightIdflight = flightIdflight;
    }

    public int getStewardIdsteward() {
        return this.stewardIdsteward;
    }

    public void setStewardIdsteward(int stewardIdsteward) {
        this.stewardIdsteward = stewardIdsteward;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if ((this == other))
            return true;
        if ((other == null))
            return false;
        if (!(other instanceof FlightHasStewardId))
            return false;
        FlightHasStewardId castOther = (FlightHasStewardId) other;

        return (this.getFlightIdflight() == castOther.getFlightIdflight())
                && (this.getStewardIdsteward() == castOther.getStewardIdsteward());
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 17;

        result = 37 * result + this.getFlightIdflight();
        result = 37 * result + this.getStewardIdsteward();
        return result;
    }

}
```

Reader.java (my class to read):

```
/* Method to READ all the stewards on specific flight */
public void getStewards(int flightid) {
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();

        // Query query = session
        // .createQuery(" FROM FlightHasSteward as FHS LEFT JOIN FHS.Flight AS F ON F.idFlight = FHS.Flight_idFlight RIGHT JOIN FHS.Steward AS S ON S.idSteward = FHS.Steward_idSteward where FHS.Flight_idFlight = :code");
        Query query = session.createQuery(" FROM FlightHasSteward where Flight_idFlight = :code");
        query.setParameter("code", flightid);
        List<FlightHasStewardId> result = query.list();

        final List<FlightHasStewardId> res = (List<FlightHasStewardId>) query.list();
        for (final FlightHasStewardId hall_calendar : res) {
            System.out.println(hall_calendar.getStewardIdsteward());
        }
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null)
            tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }

}
```

And the disturbing output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: FlightHasSteward cannot be cast to FlightHasStewardId
    at Reader.getStewards(Reader.java:97)
    at Manager.main(Manager.java:24)
```

I would appreciate any help with this case, thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're selecting from `FlightHasSteward` so the resultant `List` will contain those types rather than `FlightHasStewardId`

```
Query query = session.createQuery(" FROM FlightHasSteward where Flight_idFlight = :code");
query.setParameter("code", flightid);
List<FlightHasSteward> result = query.list();
final List<FlightHasSteward> res = (List<FlightHasSteward>) query.list();
for (final FlightHasSteward steward : res) {
        System.out.println(steward.getId().getStewardIdsteward());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. I tried that one, still resulting in the exception. I can only gain access to methods like getFlightIdFlight() if its is a FlightHasStewardId. How can I read from the FlightHasSteward but use the ID class?

Comment: Did you replace _all_ the previous occurrences of `FlightHasStewardId` with `FlightHasSteward` (project clean, redeploy, etc.)? - see update

Comment: Do I understand clearly that the Id class is not needed? Can I delete it or is it just needed for mapping?

Comment: Indeed it's can be used when doing a looking based on the composite key. This answer is aimed at resolving the `ClassCastException`

Comment: OMG. I now understand the whole thing (damn, how could I have not seen this). Thank you so much for helping my mind getting out of holiday mode. You saved me hours I think!